# How can I force embedded youtube videos to play in HD on external websites

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, video-streaming, resolution

There are a lot of answers on stack overflow and the web asking about how to embed the youtube video so that the video plays in HD by default. My question is how can you always force youtube videos to play at the highest given resolution in chrome in an external website? Is there a tampermonkey script? I can't find any video playback settings in the chrome settings or flags.

I'm asking because I'm completing an online course, and the embedded videos within are about 30 seconds long each and always default to 480p, yet they always have complex diagrams that benefit from the extra resolution. It's a pain to switch to HD every single 30 seconds.